# Using a custom /etc/hosts, what IP address should I use to instantly time out? I'm running a web server on localhost

Tags: networking, webserver, hosts

I was wondering what I should use. I have tried 129.0.0.1 which times out fairly quickly when I try to access it in a web browser but when loading a page with ads, there is a significant slowdown.

Using 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 works well considering I'm running a web server on localhost. The pages 404 quickly, but that means that I'm getting all those requests on my server access logs.

I appreciate your time and advice, thanks :).

Comment: What problem are you trying to resolve that requires an IP address that times out instantly?

Comment: your os, what applications ? need more details

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have not enabled IPv6 on your machine, you could use

```
::1 localhost6.localdomain localhost6
```